# Combine contents of multiple rows in 3NF mysql tables

Tags: sql, mysql, normalization, group-concat, 3nf

Having dutifully normalised all my data, I'm having a problem combining 3NF rows into a single row for output.
Up until now I've been doing this with server-side coding, but for various reasons I now need to select all rows related to another row, and combine them in a single row, all in MySQL...

So to try and explain:

I have three tables.

- Categories
- Articles
- CategoryArticles_3NF

A category contains **CategoryID** + titles, descriptions etc. It can contain any number of articles in the Articles table, consisting of **ArticleID** + a text field to house the content.
The **CategoryArticles** table is used to link the two, so contains both the **CategoryID** and the **ArticleID**.

Now, if I select a Category record, and I JOIN the Articles table via the linking CategoryArticles_3NF table, the result is a separate row for each article contained within that category.
The issue is that I want to output one single row for each category, containing content from *all* articles within.

If that sounds like a ridiculous request, it's because it is. I'm just using articles as a good way to describe the problem. My data is actually somewhat different.

Anyway - the only way I can see to achieve this is to use a '**GROUP_CONCAT**' statement to group the content fields together - the problem with this is that there is a limit to how much data this can return, and I need it to be able to handle significantly more.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like something that should be done in the front end without more information.

If you need to, you can increase the size limit of GROUP_CONCAT by setting the system variable *group_concat_max_len*. It has a limit based on *max_allowed_packet*, which you can also increase. I think that the max size for a packet is 1GB. If you need to go higher than that then there are some serious flaws in your design.

EDIT: So that this is in the answer and not just buried in the comments...

If you don't want to change the *group_concat_max_len* globally then you can change it for just your session with:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = <your value here>
```

Comment: Usually this is done in the front end, but for this specific issue I need it done via MySQL.
I'm running on a shared server, and therefore have no access to change the group_concat_max_len or max_allowed_packet settings.
The data will probably never exceed about 100kb.

Comment: I believe that you can set the group_concat_max_len for just your session. Try "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = <your value here>"

Comment: Right you are, that seems to work... thanks!
In the end, as time was a factor, I did it with server-side coding rather than MySQL - it's a performance issue and certainly not the way I'd wanted to handle the problem... but won't be noticable on an app this size.